# How can I get gnupg to prompt for a password in the Terminal using Python?

Tags: python, gnupg, praw

I am trying to make a Reddit script in Python, and rather than store my password in plain text, I encrypted it, from an example I found on the internet.  I am new to Python and I am not too sure how I get pinentry to pop up, and my password is not stored in my `.gnupg` folder.

I have this:

```
import praw
from praw.models import Submission
import wget
import gnupg

gpg_home = "/home/jonathan/.gnupg"
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)
gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'

stream = open('info.asc', 'rb')

def getmypasswd(stream,fields):
   stream.seek(0)
   return str(gpg.decrypt_file(stream)).split(",",2)[fields].strip()

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=getmypasswd(stream,0), client_secret=getmypasswd(stream,1), password=getmypasswd(stream,2), user_agent='python:Blarg:v1.0 (by Me)', username='BlargMe')
steam.close()
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but are you looking for the [`getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) module?

Comment: Also, what is, realistically, the advantage of doing this over `PASSWORD = input("Password: ")`?

Comment: @grooveplex Maybe, I don't know much about Python and trying to learn.  I had found this encryption method and thought it was neat, but to answer your question, there is no advantage/disadvantage.

Comment: Then why not go the easier route? :)

Comment: Yeah that does work I suppose, in the end it is the same thing, but had I still wanted to do the gpg.decrypt method, this `return str(gpg.decrypt_file(stream, p)).split(",",2)[fields].strip()` with `p = getpass.getpass()` doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with @grooveplex. If you're going to be entering a password (for the GPG key) manually in the pinentry popup, why not just save a step and enter the Reddit password directly into your script using `input` or `getpass`?

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you guys but I still want to know how I can do what I asked, just for the educational benefit, not practicality.